# Correct Boto aws DynamoDb .scan syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I've been working with Dynamo & Python for a little while now however I've run into what appears to be mismatch in syntax.

I read:

```
# All results.
>>> everything = users.scan()

# Look for last names beginning with "D".
>>> results = users.scan(last_name__beginswith='D')
>>> for res in results:
...     print res['first_name']
'Alice'
'John'
'Jane'

# Use an ``IN`` filter & limit.
>>> results = users.scan(
...     age__in=[25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
...     limit=1
... )
>>> for res in results:
...     print res['first_name']
'Alice'
```

From: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html
Which seems to agree with the scan function in boto table: https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/433f211b5eb93560916a4bd4a1dbf905e6c13a58/boto/dynamodb2/table.py

The issue lies in that when I try:

```
def getByAdvertiser(adv):
    matchingTable=swfTable.scan(advertiser__eq=adv)
    return getTableElements(matchingTable)
def getTableElements(table):
    res=[]
    for t in table:
        res.append(t)
    return res
```

Which based on the above syntax should work given that swfTable is a valid table, .scan() returns elements, that "advertiser" is a dynamo table column, and there exists at least one element in "advertiser" that is equal to adv ("itunes.apple.com"). I get the following error however:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/tai/Documents/workspace/testSelenium/testS/**init**.py", line
>   101, in 
>       forInFile()   File "/Users/tai/Documents/workspace/testSelenium/testS/**init**.py", line
>   95, in forInFile
>       dynamoAccess.getByAdvertiser("itunes.apple.com")   File "/Users/tai/Documents/workspace/testSelenium/testS/dynamoAccess.py",
>   line 34, in getByAdvertiser
>       matchingTable=swfTable.scan(advertiser__eq=adv)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/boto/dynamodb/table.py",
>   line 518, in scan
>       return self.layer2.scan(self, *args, **kw) TypeError: scan() got an unexpected keyword argument 'advertiser__eq'

I don't see how I'm not following the documentation's syntax.

However when I look at other Boto dynamodb questions they use syntax such as:

```
results = self.table.scan(scan_filter={'asset': dynamodb.condition.EQ(asset)})
```

from:

> [Trouble getting a dynamodb scan to work with boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664335/trouble-getting-a-dynamodb-scan-to-work-with-boto)

Or:

```
all_query = table.scan(attributes_to_get=['something'])
```

From: [boto python dynamodb scan attributes_to_get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006118/boto-python-dynamodb-scan-attributes-to-get)

Which looks nothing like what I'm using or anything that I've seen documented.

**EDIT:**

I believe the issue may be that I have been using dynamodb1 instead of 2.

```
aws_dynamo_table="decompiled_swf_text"
conn= S3Connection(aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key);
dynamoConn = boto.connect_dynamodb(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
dTable = dynamoConn.get_table(aws_dynamo_table)
```

Would this be solved by using dynamodb2? If so how can I set that up? I'm trying:

```
dynamoConn = dynamodb2.layer1.DynamoDBConnection(region=RegionInfo(name=aws_dynamo_region,endpoint='dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'),aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key)
```

However I don't see how I can then query and scan tables... I don't see an available function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two examples that you found are both using [traditional/low-level API](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html#low-level-api). for example in the old API, the [scan](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html#boto.dynamodb2.layer1.DynamoDBConnection.scan) function will take a scanFilter as a parameter.

And syntax like

```
>>> results = users.scan(
...     age__in=[25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
...     limit=1
... )
```

is defined in [new/high level API](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html#high-level-api).

You should definitely switch to DynamoDB2. from your error output

```
in scan return self.layer2.scan(self, *args, **kw) TypeError:
```

it seems you were using DynamoDB instead of DynamoDB2 because [layer2 API](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb.html#module-boto.dynamodb.layer2) is defined in DynamoDB api and it goes away in DynamoDB2.

So switch boto DynamoDB2

1) [get your table](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html#boto.dynamodb2.table.Table)

2) use table.scan(age__in=[25, 26, 27, 28, 29], limit=1) see [here](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html#boto.dynamodb2.table.Table.scan)